# Trinity and incarnation

Tags: nature-of-god, trinity, words-of-jesus, incarnation

If the Son does whatever the Father does (John 5:19), does that mean the Father also incarnated for the Son to incarnate?

Comment: Clearly not, for there is no documentation supporting your concept and no evidence of it ever having occurred.(Quite apart from the idea contradicting many scriptures, e.g. 1 John 4:14;)

Comment: Welcome to Christianity Stack Exchange. Please take our Tour to find out how we are different to other sites and what we look for in well-researched and valid questions: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: @NigelJ there is no evidence of it ever having occurred for Jesus either. You don’t seem to mind that there is no documentation supporting your concept of his alleged incarnation unless of course we put Creeds before Scripture and readily dismiss the contradictions created.

Answer (score 2):

In a word, no. According to Jesus Himself He rightly said at John 1:18, "No one has seen God at any time. The only begotten Son, who is in the bosom of the Father, He has declared Him." And at John 6:46, "Not that any man hath seen the Father, except he who is from God, he hath seen the Father."

John 4:24 states, "God is spirit, and those who worship Him must worship in spirit and truth." In other words, God is a spiritual being and as noted God the Father cannot be seen.

God's Son, Jesus Christ is the one and only Son of God as in there are no others. (John 3:16). Since this is true Jesus as the Son of God shares the same nature as His Father. Jesus did not have a biological father. On the other hand, Jesus also identified Himself as the "Son of Man." On His mother's side He has the same nature as His mother which is human being.

So Jesus Christ has two natures, one on His Father's side and one on His mother's side. It's a universal law that all sons share the same nature as its father. Philippians 2:6-8 teaches that Jesus Christ who always existed as God took on another form which was that of a bond-servant/man. Philippians 2:8, "And being found in appearance as a man, He humbled Himself by becoming obedient to the point of death on a cross."

At John 14:8 Philip said to Him/Jesus, Lord, show us the Father, and it is enough for us." Vs9, Jesus said to him, "Have I been so long with you, and yet you have not come to know Me, Philip? He who sees Me has seen the Father, how do you say, Show us the Father?"

Jesus here is not saying that He is God the Father, look at vs10, "Do you not believe that I am in the Father; and the Father is in Me? (Please notice two persons are in view here.) The words I say to you I do not speak on my own initiative, but the Father abiding in Me does His works."

The point of this is the fact that the Father has no separate manifestation from the Son. The Son is the only manifestation and revelation of the Father. What is known of the Father is revealed through the Son. To see the Son is to see the essence of the Father. Please read John 1:1,18; John 10:30; John 12:45; Colossians 1:15; Hebrews 1:3.)

Everything Jesus did was to please His Father and to glorify the Father. This also means that we are to follow Jesus' example in our daily life. Goin back to Philippians 2, notice what the Apostle Paul states at verse 3-5.

Starting at Vs3, Do nothing from selfishness or empty conceit, but with humility of mind let each of you REGARD ONE ANOTHER AS MORE IMPORTANT THAN HIMSELF." Vs4, do not merely look out for your own personal interest, BUT ALSO FOR THE INTEREST OF OTHERS."

Vs5, "Have this attitude in yourselves which was also in Christ Jesus." I already went over the verses that follow. The point is to follow the example of Jesus Christ and honor Him just like were suppose to honor the Father. (John 5:23).

Comment: I like this answer +1 from me (to balance out the unfair negative you received for an answer that is very Biblical!)

Comment: I also like this answer but don't understand what you mean when you say: It's a universal law that all sons share the same nature as its father. Jesus has two natures, one being human, which he got from his mother. I've inherited the nature of both my father and my mother - unless I misunderstand what you mean by "nature". Can you please clarify this one point with regard to the divine and human nature of Jesus? Thanks.

Comment: @Lesley Sure! The main point is that (for example) horses share the same nature as other horses, birds make baby birds of like kind. And technically speaking in biology the man determines the sex of a baby depending on whether their sperm is carrying an X or Y chromosome. God is not biological and Jesus did not have a biological father but did have a human mother. Matthew 1:20. Keep up the good work.

Answer (score 0):

We must consider the natures of both God the father and that of Jesus in order to understand, not only your question, but also to understand the relationship between the three who make up the Trinity.

> John 5:19 KJV  ***Then answered Jesus and said unto them, Verily, verily, I say unto you, The Son can do nothing of himself, but what he seeth the Father do:*** for what things soever he doeth, these also doeth the Son likewise. 
> Joh 5:20  For the Father loveth the Son, and sheweth him all things that himself doeth: and he will shew him greater works than these, that ye may marvel.

The one commonality between the Trinity is that they are all Spirits.

> John 4:23  But the hour cometh, and now is, when the true worshippers shall worship the Father in spirit and in truth: for the Father seeketh such to worship him. 
> 24  **God is a Spirit: and they that worship him must worship him in spirit and in truth.**

When Jesus conversed with the other two in the Trinity, They conversed in the spirit. Therefore; when Jesus maintains that he could do nothing on his own; what he was alluding to was the fact that being spiritually bonded together all things were from the tripartite God.

> Matthew 12:28  But if ***I cast out devils by the Spirit of God,*** then the kingdom of God is come unto you.

Note that Jesus said **he cast out devils** by the ***spirit of God***.God works in the Spiritual Realm; and we too often think of things in our earthly concepts.

Hope this helps

Comment: Luke 24 39 You might be misinterpreting this Scripture, or my reference to the trinity. That particular Scripture is explicitly there to show that God the father has reinstated the life of the man Jesus; which only applies to his physical life; not unlike his creation of Adam where God breathed the breath of life into Adams body formed from the dust of the Earth. As far as my referring to the Trinity inclusion all three are Spirits with no beginning or end.

Comment: Beckhum Luke 24.39 is not referring to Jesus still being a spirit. His words specifically say the opposite to such a view! People simply do not appreciate that Jesus took upon humanity permanently. His God man status is not just for the approx 33/34 years he was on this earth. Remember the angels said to the disciples "this same Jesus will come in exactly the same manner you saw him ascend into heaven"

Comment: @Adam Not meaning to be snippy but the name BECKUM and not Beckhum. However you may like to call me Cecil which is fine. Yes it is in reference to his physical body which we know died and if it did not there would be no Salvation. The fact that that physical body which did die, has been revived and lives again; bears witness to the fact that our resurrection bodies can also live again after dyeing. That bears witness to our Salvation in Christ. Jesus  in his resurrection body was still both Man and God and God is a Spirit.

Comment: @ Cecil I am a trinitarian. GOD consists of 3 entities, the Father, Son, and Holy Spirit. The Son is now a man (translated as were Enoch and Elijah). Whether the Father is Spirit or not...I would need to see Biblical evidence for that because if there is already a Holy Spirit, why does the Father also need to be one? Conversely, if the Father is not spirit, what is He?

Comment: @Adam Apparently you have a concept of God that is not the one I have. Therefore to continue this back and forth; can serve no useful purpose. So let us no longer continue it. With Christian love thanks Cecil.

Comment: @ Cecil I am struggling to understand what your view of God is? It appears that you believe the incarnation is not permanent, rather Jesus now flicks between the two whenever it suits Him. That is a gross misinterpretation of scripture in my view. Jesus visit to the disciples in upper room (and words to Thomas put your finger in my side) was after he had already been to heaven. Remember what he said to Mary outside the tomb earlier. Jesus also refers to Himself as the Son of Man at second coming.